# Draggable/Sortable nesting issue (error in onDragStart)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, drag-and-drop, sortablejs, vuedraggable

I'd like to both drag the row of items as well as the items itself, within the same or across different rows. It works until I try to move the last item of a row which then results in an error.

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/lexixon/nf97erqx/64/

Error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'element' of null
    at VueComponent.onDragStart (vuedraggable.js:380)
    at mt.<anonymous> (vuedraggable.js:37)
    at Ct (Sortable.min.js:3)
    at mt._dragStarted (Sortable.min.js:3)

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'index' of null
    at VueComponent.onDragRemove (vuedraggable.js:403)
    at mt.<anonymous> (vuedraggable.js:37)
    at Ct (Sortable.min.js:3)
    at mt._onDrop (Sortable.min.js:3)
    at mt.handleEvent (Sortable.min.js:3)
```